# Finding average of row of 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm creating a method that finds the average of doubles in a row of a 2D array. The method takes in a char that describes the grade category which is the row. From that, I need to find the average of all of the items in that row. How can I find the row and calculate the average?

Here's what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class GradeBook {

private String name;
private char[] categoryCodes;
private String[] categories;
private double[] categoryWeights;
private double[][] gradeTable;

public GradeBook(String nameIn, char[] categoryCodesIn, 
  String[] categoriesIn, double[] categoryWeightsIn) {

  name = nameIn;
  categoryCodes = categoryCodesIn;
  categories = categoriesIn;
  categoryWeights = categoryWeightsIn;
  gradeTable = new double[5][0];
 }
 public double categoryAvg (char gradeCategory) {

    double sum = 0.0;
    double count = 0.0;
    int index = 0; 

    if (gradeCategory == 'a')
        index = 0;
    else if (gradeCategory == 'q')
        index = 1;
    else if (gradeCategory == 'p')
        index = 2;
    else if (gradeCategory == 'e')
        index = 3;
    else if (gradeCategory == 'f')
        index = 4;

    return sum / count;
  }
}
```

Comment: In your code is nothing that handles with an array. Please post all code related to your problem

Comment: And since `count` is 0 every time, you'll get an [`ArithmeticException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html) at your `return` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the row is selected all you have to do is a simple 1D-array average on that row.
Something like:

```
for(int i=0; i < array[index].length; i++){
      sum = sum + array[index][i];
      count++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add something like this to the end so you don't try to divide by zero:

```
if (count == 0) {
    return 0;
} else {
    return sum / count;
}
```